# JavaScript - Custom message depending on the time of day

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement

The idea is that the user can input a name and depending on the time of day it would say 'good morning x' or 'good evening X'. This is what my code currently looks like :

```
function myFunction()
{
var person=prompt("Please enter your name");
var d = new Date();
d.getHours(); 
d.getMinutes(); 





if (person!==null)
  {
    if(d.getHours() < 12){
    x = "Have a great morning " + person;
}
    else{
    x = "Have a great afternoon " + person;
    }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
```

When I press the button that runs the function I get this :

```
function getHours() { [native code] }:41
```

Frankly I have no idea where to go from here so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can we see the button? I am assuming you're calling the function without the `()`

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to launch the greeting app
</button> Here it is

Comment: The code is working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/9AN7n/

Comment: @tewathia you added a `{` though didn't you? Unless that was a copy/paste error he's missing it after the `if(d.getHours() < 12){`

Comment: No idea how but I've copied your code and pasted it over mine and it works. Must have been some minor formatting slip up. Well thanks!

Comment: @Phil I added a `}` at the end, to close the `myFunction` definition. I just assumed that was a copy-paste error

Comment: @LukaszMedza Also, you don't need the `d.getHours()` and `d.getMinutes()` lines. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/9AN7n/2/

Answer (score -1):

There is a syntax error.
Add a close brace at the end of the function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name");
    var d = new Date();
    d.getHours();
    d.getMinutes();

    if (person !== null) {
        if (d.getHours() < 12) {
            x = "Have a great morning " + person;
        } else {
            x = "Have a great afternoon " + person;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather add a `}` at the end of the if statement